# AJAX weird redirection?

Tags: php, ajax

I have some AJAX code that is redirecting when button is pressed.

It is redirecting to members.php

This is the AJAX code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxFunction(){
            var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

            try{
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e){
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e){
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Please update your browser.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            // We still need to write some code here
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    // Get the data from the server's response
                    response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "accept.php?id=<?php echo $articleid; ?>&state=accept$p=a9dafdd0fe68c6f64841e265e1c8832a", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);                 
    }       

</script>
```

And this is the button:

```
<input type="submit" onChange="ajaxFunction();" />
```

And this is the contents of accept.php:

```
<?php
    echo "ACCEPTED";
?>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Add `onsubmit="return false;"` in `form` tag.

Comment: so it is redirecting, which is wrong, or is supposed to be redirecting...? what should it do? If you don't want it to redirect anywhere, add "return false" in either onlick of the button or onsubmit on the form, like others have mentioned.

Comment: It is redirecting and I don't want it to.    PLB I tried that code in the form tag but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" onChange="ajaxFunction();" />

should be

<input type="submit" onclick="ajaxFunction();" />
```

and use  `return false;` at the end of your function

or you can use simple jquery

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
// or $("#form").submit(function(){
$.get("accept.php?id=<?php echo $articleid; 
?>&state=accept&p=a9dafdd0fe68c6f64841e265e1c8832a",function(data){
rasponce=data;
  })

 return false;
})
```

Comment: It's still redirecting to members.php :(

Answer (score 0):

what is this?

```
"&state=accept$p=a9dafdd0fe68c6f64841e265e1c8832a",
```

... should it be something like

```
"&state=accept&p=a9dafdd0fe68c6f64841e265e1c8832a",
```

Comment: but which part is the data? you need to have `&` if you intend to pass `a9dafdd0fe68c6f64841e265e1c8832a` as a query parameter. `$p` won't work there.

Answer (score 0):

members.php is the action on your form?  If so I'd remove the action and try it again, to see what happens.

Comment: form must have action in order for it to be valid HTML.

Comment: I made it action to action="". Still redirects to members.php

Comment: I'd get rid of the submit and just have a button.  Then you can use a click() handler to do your call.